# how can i connect my list-of-product page with my single-product page using the id of the product?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have this page with a list of products :

```
const ItemView = ({ item }) => {

    return (
     <ScrollView  style={styles.itemStyle}>
       <View style={styles.itenviewStyle}>
         <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProduitDescription') } >
         <Text> {item.id}</Text>
         <Text> {item.nom.toUpperCase()}</Text>
         <Text>{item.name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
      
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };
```

and i want to connect it to a single and detailed page(produitDescrition) of the clicked (onPress) product from the listproduct page.

maybe the code i have is already not the right way to start, tell me if that's the case.

i tried to add a key parameter with item.id in it and then fetch it with a onPress parameter to the produitDescription page :

```
<TouchableOpacity  key={item.id} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProduitDescription/${item.id}') } >
```

here is the code of my produitDescrition page :

```
const  ProduitDescription = ({navigation }) => {

  return (
    
      <ScrollView >
       <View style={styles.header}>
         <View style={{marginLeft:40,marginTop:130}}>
         <Text style={{fontSize:25,fontWeight:'bold',marginTop:20}}>item.name</Text>

         <View style={{flexDirection:"row",marginTop:10}}>
          <Text>item.adress</Text>
          <Text style={{marginLeft:15,color:"green"}}>item.description</Text>
         </View>
         </View>
       </ScrollView >
  )
}
```

and i also had this code to be able to reach my datas from my db :

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://192.168.87.144:3000/medicaments')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setFilteredDataSource(responseJson);
        setMasterDataSource(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: I think you could do that do using a flatlist since it's in-built. You may wanna take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164226/pagination-using-flatlist-in-react-native-next-previous

Comment: sorry it actually is a flatlist but i did it bcs i just learned to do list of stuff that way without really knowing the particularities of a flatlist.